# Plotly: How to put two 3D graphs on the same plot with plotly.graph_objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, plotly, plotly-python

In below code, I draw 2 3D graphs with `plotly.graph_objects`. I'm unable to put them together.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

pts = np.loadtxt(np.DataSource().open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/mesh_dataset.txt'))
x, y, z = pts.T

### First graph
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z,
                   alphahull=5,
                   opacity=0.4,
                   color='cyan')])
fig.show()
#######

x = [0, 1, 0]
y = [0, 2, 3]
tvects = [x,y]
orig = [0,0,0]
df=[]
coords = [[orig, np.sum([orig, v],axis=0)] for v in tvects]

for i,c in enumerate(coords):
    X1, Y1, Z1 = zip(c[0])
    X2, Y2, Z2 = zip(c[1])
    vector = go.Scatter3d(x = [X1[0],X2[0]],
                          y = [Y1[0],Y2[0]],
                          z = [Z1[0],Z2[0]],
                          marker = dict(size = [0,5],
                                        color = ['blue'],
                                        line=dict(width=5,
                                                  color='DarkSlateGrey')),
                          name = 'Vector'+str(i+1))
    data.append(vector)

### Second graph
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
########
```

Could you please elaborate on how to do so, and how to have the arrow with head rather than a line in the second graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to build on your first `fig` definition, just include the following after your first call to `go.Figure()`

```
data = fig._data
```

`data` is now a list which will have new elements appended to it in the rest of your already exising code under:

```
for i,c in enumerate(coords):
    X1, Y1, Z1 = zip(c[0])
    X2, Y2, Z2 = zip(c[1])
    vector = go.Scatter3d(<see details in snippet below>)
    data.append(vector)
```

#### Result:

[image]

Regarding the arrows, the only options dierectly available to you through `go.Scatter3D` are:

```
['circle', 'circle-open', 'square', 'square-open','diamond', 'diamond-open', 'cross', 'x']
```

I hope one of those options will suit your needs. You can specify which one in:

```
marker = dict(size = [15,15],
            color = ['blue'],
            symbol = 'diamond',
            line=dict(width=500,
                      #color='red'
                     )),
```

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

pts = np.loadtxt(np.DataSource().open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/mesh_dataset.txt'))
x, y, z = pts.T

### First graph
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z,
                   alphahull=5,
                   opacity=0.4,
                   color='cyan')])
#fig.show()
#######

data = fig._data

x = [0, 1, 0]
y = [0, 2, 3]
tvects = [x,y]
orig = [0,0,0]
df=[]
coords = [[orig, np.sum([orig, v],axis=0)] for v in tvects]

# ['circle', 'circle-open', 'square', 'square-open','diamond', 'diamond-open', 'cross', 'x']

for i,c in enumerate(coords):
    X1, Y1, Z1 = zip(c[0])
    X2, Y2, Z2 = zip(c[1])
    vector = go.Scatter3d(x = [X1[0],X2[0]],
                          y = [Y1[0],Y2[0]],
                          z = [Z1[0],Z2[0]],
                          marker = dict(size = [15,15],
                                        color = ['blue'],
                                        symbol = 'diamond',
                                        line=dict(width=500,
                                                  #color='red'
                                                 )),
                          name = 'Vector'+str(i+1))
    data.append(vector)

### Second graph
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
########
```

Comment: May I ask how to have an arrow head for each vector?

Comment: @LAD Haven't found a way to implement an arrow, but at least you have other options. Take a look at my last edit.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `data` argument in  `go.Figure()` accepts a list of plot objects as input. Try something like the code below:

```
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=data['tilt'].to_numpy(), y=data['pan'].to_numpy(), z=data['z'].to_numpy(),
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(size=5, color='red', opacity=1)
        ),
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=samples[:, 0], y=samples[:, 1], z=samples[:, 2], mode='markers',
            marker=dict(size=5, color='blue', opacity=1)
        )
    ])
```

and you will get something like in the image:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLbly.png)